# MouseWheelEventArgs firing twice

Tags: c#, mouseevent

Here's my code

When the event is registered:

```
this.backgroundCanvas.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventHandler(this.backgroundCanvas_MouseWheel);
```

How it is handle

```
private void backgroundCanvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            int zoomPercent = zoomManager.zoomChange(e.Delta);
        }
```

The thing that I don't understand is why my event is firing twice. I only have one listener and one reference of the handler in my code.

Comment: It is a wheel, it depends on much you turn it.  The detents in your mouse don't have to be equal to e.Delta.  It is also a system setting, Control Panel > Mouse > Wheel tab.  Getting the event fired multiple times should never cause a problem.

Comment: I only scroll once with the wheel. Even if i change my settings.

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense.  It is like saying "I only moved the mouse once".  You still get multiple MouseMove events, the intermediate positions are reported as well.  The wheel doesn't work any differently.

Comment: For me the event firing multiple is a real issue because behind that I've made a zoom system so instead of zooming once it zoom twice.If i understand correctyle,  for you the issue come from my mouse.

Comment: Hey Arthur Coudert, Did u find any solution for it ? Kindly share.

Comment: It's been a long time since i've fix this issue.

try e.Handled = true; at the end of your method